# Shortcut to create automatic properties using Visual Studio 2008/2010 or Resharper 5

Tags: c#, visual-studio, resharper, keyboard-shortcuts

I have a class that contains a load of properties that contain results of some calculations e.g:

```
public class Results
{
    public double Result1 { get; set; }
    public double Result2 { get; set; }
}
```

In a different class I am doing calculations to populate the above properties, e.g:

```
public class Calc
{
    private Results Calc()
    {
        Results res = new Results();
        res.Result1 = ... some calculation
        res.Result2 = ... some other calculation

        res.Result3 = ... // not yet defined in 'Results' class
        return res;
    }
}
```

When I am writing the `Calc` class, `Result3` will be highlighted in red as it is not yet defined in the `Results` class.

Currently I am using the Resharper <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> shortcut, selecting "Create Property 'Result3'" which will create the following code int the `Results` class:

```
public double Result3
{
    get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    set { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
}
```

Which I need to manually change to:

```
public double Result3 { get; set; }
```

Then I use the <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Backspace</kbd> shortcut to take me back to the `Calc` class.

How can I easily create automatic properties in the `Results` class if they are not yet defined directly from the `Calc` class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you'd like to stay in the `Calc` class and create your properties in `Results` in one go.

Here's what you do.

1. Turn on Solution-wide error checking
   (Resharper 5 is considerably
   better/faster)
2. Edit `Calc` referring to all `Results` properties, leaving the errors reported.
3. Hit <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>PageDown</kbd>.  That will cycle you through all your errors.
4. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> and choose Create Property and use the Auto-Property choice in `Results`, then hit <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>PageDown</kbd> to
   get back to `Calc`

Answer (score 7):

For Resharper 4/5, type `prop` then tab, then fill in the required parameters.

Comment: I know about the 'prop' template but that means I have to go to the Results class and create it manually. I want to be able to do this as I am writing the Calc class.

Comment: The `prop` shortcut appears to work native to VS.NET 2010 as well without Resharper to create auto-properties.

Answer (score 2):

As soon as you've pressed <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> to create the property, and then <kbd>Enter</kbd> to accept the data type, you actually get a drop-down list of ways of implementing it if you're on a recent version of ReSharper. One of them is auto property.

Comment: I am using Resharper 5 and I only see four options when I Alt-Enter on it:
create field ...
create property ...
Change all ...
Change all local ...

Comment: Yes. Create property. Then it creates it and takes you to it. The data type will be highlighted. Press enter to accept the data type. Then you see the choice of property implementation.

Comment: Ah, I see that now, thanks for highlighting that feature. I can use it to remove one step. Would still like to do this all in as few key presses as possible.

Comment: Hmm, I seem to have to do: Alt-Enter, Down, Enter, Tab, Down, Down, Enter - 7 steps :)